# Form hiding after clicking the mobile keyboard submit/go button

Tags: css, html, forms, angular, mobile

In my mobile app, the following UI has two textboxes and the submit button wrapped in a `<form>`.

When I enter the credentials and hit the submit button it goes to the next page. No problems. But instead if I enter the credentials and tap on the "Go/Submit" button on the soft keyboard, the form area disappears for awhile before navigating to the next page like in the image below.

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How do you submit your form? If you're listening to `(click)` event on submit button, you might try to listen to form [submit event](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html#!#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit-):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```